# Is the bar lower for literary theory?

Tags: metaphilosophy, literary-theory

Is the bar lower for literary theory? Is argumentation a lot less demanding, i.e. it needn't be as convincing?

I mean literary criticism as it is informed by its underlying principles (formalism, new criticism, structuralism, etc.)

> ["Literary theory"](http://www.iep.utm.edu/literary) is the body of ideas and methods we use in the
>   practical reading of literature. By literary theory we refer not to
>   the meaning of a work of literature but to the theories that reveal
>   what literature can mean.

Or is this doing of literary theory just as demanding of rational argument?

Comment: Have you read Derrida? It is by no means easy.

Comment: @Canyon reading Derrida? being Derrida? in fact i meant arguing as soundly as Derrida (et al)

Comment: My point is that the ideas he is dealing with are by no means trivial. In fact his analyses are incredibly rigorous and detailed.

Comment: @Canyon ok then demonstrate his rigour -- in an answer. please do !

Comment: A lot of literary theory is more continental than analytic (especially looking at the last century's literary criticism/continental philosophy as a whole, e.g. marxism, post-structuralism, psychoanalysis, etc.) and I don't think its controversial to say that continental philosophy is less rigorous than analytic philosophy. The line between the styles is very blurry with regards to contemporary (post turn of the century) work, a lot of the analytic schools' rigor made it into discussions about continental work. This is seen in literary criticism as well.

Comment: @user25714 Have you read Foucault? (Or would you rather call him and all good theorists "philosophers"?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone like Kuhn might argue that "the bar is lower" for all pre- or inter-paradigmatic sciences.  The reasons that we can demand compliance with a standard is there is an understood and accepted standard.

Clinical Psychology is a parallel example.  One can look at Freud and shake one's head at his strange evasiveness, which made for a science so weak it prompted people to put up walls against considering it science.  But without Freud, a lot of later people would never have said things that are genuinely useful.

Philology and therefore Literary Criticism is, unfortunately or otherwise, a domain that borrows paradigms until they come to mean something, and when they do not pay off, it moves on.  So there is no paradigm, unless one chooses one.  Subdisciplines of the field do have paradigms.  If you choose to work in a paradigm, one should hold oneself to the standards already set by earlier contributors.

(On that basis, one might say that it is just as demanding *unless* you want to innovate.  Being caught up in the paradigm of the day may actually be a form of laziness.  It be something that makes literary analysis worse, if a different lens would suit the author better.)

Comment: Hopefully you will get some from somewhere closer to your mark than the philosophy of science.  But thanks.

Comment: _Not_ good answer, imo. Can you put up some evidence that literary theorists play with paradigms until they get bored?

Comment: @Canyon Literary Marxism.  Critical Theory itself.  The fascination with psychoanalytic techniques.  All of these just rose and fell, mostly because folks in the domain don't like being constrained.  On the other hand, there are deep, traditional schools of criticism that are still alive -- see New Criterion, etc.

Comment: hyperbole. we can say "gets bored" of anyone who abandons an allegedly principled position (Adorno) @Canyon

Comment: @Canyon.  Hyperbole requires a moderate position exists.  Is there some milder way of saying this that is not just lying?  Adorno stayed within his paradigm, even when his central references changed, so he is a very odd exemplar of whatever position you think applies here.

Comment: Why would we not think that they moved on in exactly the same way philosophy has moved on from logical positivism? (That is, it has its heyday, it still has adherents, but in the main we no longer think it is the best way to look at the world.) Can you support your claim that people switch paradigms because they don't like being constrained rather than because they think some other paradigm is better?

Comment: @Canyon Because philosophy still studies logical positivism.  We still follow it through and see how it fails.  We learn Goedel and Quine.  Critical Theory is completely optional.

Comment: @Canyon You are free to give contrary proof, or write your own answer.  But just diagnosing me, without answering my questions is not going to get me to change anything.  Arguments have more content that 'that insults me'.

Comment: I probably will, but I'm not diagnosing you---I'm pointing out that you have failed to support your answer. If you have a proof of your hot take on literary theory I would love to read it!

Comment: @Canyon i think that jobermark is saying that innovation needs "standards" beyond being interesting / speculative, even being true. these are suspended

Comment: @user3293056  Eh.  that is the 'unfortunately or otherwise' part.  I am not sure that LC paradigms are a wonderful thing.  It would be horrible if at this point Clinical Philosophy chose a paradigm for itself.  There really is not enough data.  And it might be equally horrible if Literary Theory stopped cycling through options.  But they do just cycle through options, trying to find something worth keeping.  Philosophy evolves, but it keeps its whole history, and keeping the whole history is part of its paradigm.

Comment: @user3293056  I have yet to hear an argument, so I am not even sure we disagree.  I think someone just does not like my language, because they find it dismissive.  But I really cannot think of another way to put it.  It may happen that our way of looking at literature will converge, or it may splinter into different disciplines.  But if it stays a single field, and goes on as it is, it is a perpetually preparadigmatic form of knowledge.

Comment: @Canyon  I have made a stab at being less offensive, but I think the data speak for themselves.  The field just goes through phases and accumulates subdisciplines, much like Clinical Philosophy (one of the fields in which I have actually worked) still does half the time.

Comment: @jobermark as far as i can tell your answer answers the question as good as it's about to be

Comment: @user3293056 A mechanical point.  You don't need to bury that in a comment.  You, as the author of the question can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I think if one is making an argument that assumes there is common sense, and it is basically clear and distinct, i.e., scientific, then it follows that all arguments that won't work on an intelligent but stubborn elderly fellow, ought to be thrown out, then there are either good arguments or ones that don't convince.

On the other hand, once one assumes that there is a question about common sense, all kinds of opacity follows. And anything can be justified on this basis, so that the matter of distinguishing serious from frivolous becomes a matter of special ability. Just as not anyone can make sound judgments about music or other issues, basically objective (as a sense is, not as the sciences are), but requiring talent. Thus, elitism becomes a great charge, and many other charges come in due to various forms difficulty, both in the current system of training, the universities, and for reasons intrinsic to an activity which at the peak, only a very few are competent to judge.

Comment: i'm voting down because your answer is pretty vacuous TO ME if not meant simply to disparage the character / intelligence of the question. which is just dull IN THE EXTREME

Comment: Perhaps you don't understand what is at issue with common sense; what that would mean? For instance that antebellum Southerners would be more likely to hold that Slavery is justified. Or, that men in the past held the earth stood quite still. Or, that Hume challenges the common sense notion of causality.

Comment: i don't really feel inclined to talk about it. are you saying that your careerist interpretation of such things as truth is especially privileged cos it's idiosyncratic ?

Comment: If common sense changes it justifies all kinds of funny arguments. I.e., arguments that make no sense. This applies to the criteria for arguments too. The so-called "low bar", is there one criterion, or many? One common sense, or many...

Comment: surely, many.  how could it not be?

Comment: Literary Theory isn't about literature mainly, but the world. It's just a name for a specific kind of philosophy.

Comment: @Dwaf if you like.

Comment: "Philologists" are called Classicists these days.

Comment: Literary Theorists, e.g., Philippe Lacoue-Labarthe, are philosophers. But the difference is, largely, they have been impressed by certain developments in philosophy that those more impressed by the sciences have not been. I think your question is somewhat misguided.

Comment: dogma often finds questions misguided?

Comment: "Dogma" usually implies a claim to be true, rather than merely to communicate.  Ergo, it seems strange to call conventional names like "philosophy" or "Literary Theory" and their ordinary usage, "dogma". It is like saying the dictionary is an apodictic document. Very funny!

Comment: it's just not interesting, or sound, to complain that someone has failed to communicate on the grounds that you can read them uncharitably, i wasn't doing that in the question

Comment: also how does 'dogma' "imply" anything of the sort. enjoy yourself, i'm done trying to speak sense.

Comment: What the example I gave is meant to signal is that the people who are subsumed under the title Literary Theorist, if one looks, are called philosophers on their Wiki pages & in other commonly accepted publications. I.e, by convention or common usage: Literary Theorists are Philosophers. But that signals something more substantive, which is what my answer delineates very crudely.  "Theory" derives more from Political Philosphy's downgoing, as it were, especially starting in the 50's "Political Theory" came in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60345/discussion-between-user3293056-and-dwarf).

Comment: Most Literary Theorists who choose a paradigm apply philosophy to the domain of communication.  They generally use philosophy that is already elaborated, (often already discredited) and apply it to fiction or to discourse, to see if it gives the art a different interpretation.  They are not developing original philosophy, or their whole endeavor loses traction.  If you are changing the rules, you cannot also be applying them.

Comment: That sounds like a bit of the stuff itself.In the form of an extrinsic deprecatory theory of theory. That hangs on what "philosophy" means. "Original" is also rather too vague, remember the word of that fatal Britisher who said all Philosophy came out from under the over-coat of Socrates, or, said in another way: Philosophy is "foot note" to Plato, thus, elaboration/development/amplification.I fear, these days, "originality" means any change of the tiles on a scrabble board. I.e., the "originality" of the philosophy professors is more like the sophistry of moving stickers on a refrigerator.

Comment: Dwarf, am I right that you are speaking in your answer (abruptly) about “common sense” because you (tacitly) associate literary criticism to be an antipole of common sense; or do I misunderstand that? — If yes, so you hence discuss the duality `{literature criticism` vs. `common sense/philosophy/science}?` — My just proposed edit is motivated in this sense.

Comment: I think one has to distinguish Literary Criticism, newspapers, large volumes of collected articles about novels, & books written by English professors, &, on the other side, Literary Theory, which I take to be the name of the kind of work people like Jacques Derrida Roland Barthes and Avital Ronell, are sometimes said to have done or do. The later is often used as a deprecatory name, for what one calls in the vernacular, philosophy. I take the work of someone like Harold Bloom to be roughly common-sensical, ergo: Literary Criticism. Someone like Eric Auerbach, makes the issue more unclear.